# Is there anything wrong with my MySql Select query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to fetch some results from database using Ajax request :

```
SELECT * 
FROM manifest_child 
WHERE manifest_id = $manifest_id
AND s_no = $sub_id
AND branch_code = '$branch_code'
        ";
```

Everything looks fine but it is giving an error when I pass some value in it:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND s_no = 3 AND branch_code = 'KHI'' at line 3
```

I'm stuck in that, Anyone Please Help me out, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think something is wrong on `$manifest_id `. Try to check it.

Comment: Try outputting the query so you can see what it looks like. You should put single quotation marks around the variables, if it anything other than an integer it will error.

Comment: Nope, sir, I tried different spaces but no gain :(

Comment: @Tristan the query works fine in MYSQL tab in phpmyadmin, then why is it giving SQL Syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer, It was giving a mysql error because $manifest_id was getting a null value, therefore the WHERE clause was not getting satisfied, I did not noticed because the mysql error was not showing the null part in the error.
I tried to query in a different way,the error was still there but in a different way :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=AND s_no = 3 AND branch_code = 'KHI'' at line 3
```

Notice the equal sign preceding the AND keyword. Thanks Everyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

may be the line breaks try this

```
$que = "SELECT * FROM manifest_child".
        "WHERE   manifest_id     = $manifest_id".
        "AND     s_no            = $sub_id".
        "AND     branch_code     = '$branch_code'";
```

Comment: I tried your query, and i got the same error but in a different way, I've mentioned it in my answer below, I cannot mark your answer as an answer but it was actually an answer, sounds weird, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Splitting a query over multiple lines inside a quoted string (as in the original) is fine. This answer just makes the sql harder to read and edit etc.

Comment: @Berniv have you seen first comment?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `manifest_id` ans `s_no` are not integers, so wrap them with quotes. Try this

```
$que = "SELECT * FROM manifest_child 
        WHERE manifest_id = '$manifest_id' 
        AND s_no = '$sub_id' 
        AND branch_code = '$branch_code'";
```

Comment: Nope sir, They are integers

Comment: just check with the query once. See if you get same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not safe for SQL Injection
You must do that:

```
$que = mysql_escape_string($que);
$que = "SELECT * FROM manifest_child 
    WHERE   manifest_id     = $manifest_id 
    AND     s_no            = $sub_id 
    AND     branch_code     = '$branch_code'
    ";
```

in this way your code will be much safer and you will ran away from this error.
I think the error because you put another ' (qute) when you pass the parameter.

Comment: All of these variable are refined by mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: from the error code you provide `'AND s_no = 3 AND branch_code = 'KHI''`
notice that you have double quotes after KHI
So you must know from where it come